# Show that the postulates of probability are satisfied by conditional probabilities. In other words, show that is P(B) does not equal 0 then:

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I did prove all three of the postulates. I was just hoping someone could look them over to see if I proved it correctly? Thank you!

1. P(A|B) >= 0 (This is what I'm proving!)

   P(A|B) = P(AnB)/P(B)

   1>(or equal to) P(B) > 0

   P(AnB) c P(B) therefore, P(AnB) < P(B)

   Then, P(B)> P(AnB) >(or equal to) 0

   So, P(A|B) must be >= 0
2. P(B|B) = 1 (I'm pretty positive I proved this correctly so I'm going to leave the proof out)
3. P(A1 u A2 u ... |B) = P(a1|B) + P(A2|B) + ... for any sequence of mutually exclusive   events A1, A2, ... (This is what I'm proving)

   P(A1 u A2 u ... |B) = P[(A1 u A2 u...) n B)]/ P(B)

   I know that P[(A1 u A2 u...)n B]  is disjoint

   Then, P(A1 n B) + P(A2 n B) + ...

   so now I have [P(A1 n B) + P(A2 n B) +...] / P(B)

   I know that P(A1 n B)/ P(B) <=> P(A1|B) and P(A2 n B)/ P(B) <=> P(A2|B)

   So, P(A1 u A2 u ... |B) = P(a1|B) + P(A2|B) + ...

Comment: (1) seems more complicated than it needs to be. $P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ is a nonnegative number divided by a nonnegative number that's explicitly assumed nonzero; such quotients of real numbers are always nonnegative. (3) is definitely the right idea, but I would ask for more details (for example, what do you mean when you say "$P[(A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots) \cap B]$ is disjoint"? and then how do you know that's true?) and more accurate sentences (what does <=> mean in the penultimate line? In the 4th-to-last line, "Then, blah" isn't a sentence.).